# Iterating an ordered path variable in a for loop

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop

I have the following txt document:

```
deviceIDs.txt

UDID0=LGH811dec0bfd6
UDID1=41006289e4b2a179
UDID2=d9a7aa45

PORT0=4567
PORT1=4568
PORT2=4569

BOOTPORT0=5556
BOOTPORT1=5557
BOOTPORT2=5558
```

I want to be able to write the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /path/deviceIDs.txt
for ((i=0;i<=2;i++))
do
    echo $UDID$i
    echo $PORT$i
    echo $BOOTPORT$i
done
```

however this doesn't work. Presumable because the dollar sign is being used twice in one expression. I've tried formatting the variables using {} too but still no success.

Comment: [How can I use variable variables (indirect variables, pointers, references) or associative arrays?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006)

Comment: `source` the file and then use what @EtanReisner suggests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use bash's form of *indirection*:

```
#!/bin/bash
source deviceIDs.txt
for ((i=0;i<=2;i++))
do
    for x in UDID PORT BOOTPORT
    do
        y=$x$i
        echo ${!y}
    done
done
```

The key here is that `${!y}` returns the value of the variable that is named by `y`.

This produces the output:

```
LGH811dec0bfd6
4567
5556
41006289e4b2a179
4568
5557
d9a7aa45
4569
5558
```

#### Alternative

If we are allowed to change the data file format, consider defining your variables as arrays this way:

```
$ cat IDarrays.txt 
UDID=(LGH811dec0bfd6 41006289e4b2a179 d9a7aa45)
PORT=(4567 4568 4569)
BOOTPORT=(5556 5557 5558)
```

With that, the script can be written:

```
#!/bin/bash
source IDarrays.txt
for ((i=0;i<=2;i++))
do
    echo ${UDID[$i]}
    echo ${PORT[$i]}
    echo ${BOOTPORT[$i]}
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't knew John1024's solution with !y.

If you can't modify deviceIDs.txt because it is generated by someone out of your control, you could use arrays like this too:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /path/deviceIDs.txt
u=($UDID{0..2});p=($PORT{0..2});b=($BOOTPORT{0..2})
for i in {0..2}; do echo -e ${u[i]}"\n"${p[i]}"\n"${b[i]}"\n"; done 
LGH811dec0bfd6
4567
5556

41006289e4b2a179
4568
5557

d9a7aa45
4569
5558
```

Comment: As John1024's answer and the link from Etan show, there is actually another way to do it in bash as well